# eGPU + Blender + Cycles + Mac

Tags: gpu

Hi I wanted know if anyone is using an external GPU with blender on a Mac successfully. Would anyone care if so what setup they have and any indication of benefits and pitfalls.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I recently made this build, have a look. It has some bench marks from blender: 
https://egpu.io/forums/mac-setup/macbook-pro-retina-15-inch-early-2013-akitio-node-1080-ti-external-monitor/#post-14571

[image]