# External GPU for 2016 Macbook Pro

Tags: gpu, osx, hardware

I am running Blender on a 2016 Macbook Pro that is not equipped for rendering. My renders are taking ages (6 to 8 hours to render wooden products on white background). I want to make interiors renders so I need to upgrade my setup.

I am considering an external GPU for my mac but I don't now what solution to use for:

- the enclosure hardware
- the graphic card

If you guys can help me on that, I would be really pleased

Thanks

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128693/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76830/

Comment: For the kind of money that External GPU enclosures cost, you might consider buying a PC and a Nvidia GPU card to render and work on blender.

Comment: Buying a PC was an option but the idea is to keep my worflow on the same machine.
I also use mac for a decade now and don't want to go back to PC